# How to find contours from a webcam frame using opencv and c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

My goal is to find contours by capturing frame from a webcam. I was able to do it with static images but then I tried to use the same concept in a webcam frame and its giving me this error:

```
"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN
(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in cv::_OutputArray::create, f
ile C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc11-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp
, line 1486"
```

This is the code that I used to find the contours in my program;

```
 Rng rng(12345);

    Mat captureframe,con,threshold_output;

    vector<vector<Point> > contours; //
   vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    while(true)
            {
                capturedevice>>captureframe;
                con = captureframe.clone();
                cvtColor(captureframe,con,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    threshold( con, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
     findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

     Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );

     drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
    }


    imshow("contour drawing",drawing);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you may have a problem with the types of your matrices, to be sure you need to show the initialization of your variable or what ever happens before the while

Comment: @Engine:-  I have added the initialization .Any idea where i might have made a mistake?

Comment: but I don't have opencv right now, so I can really test, my hint will be that you don't need: con = captureframe.clone(); since you'Re cloning  the BGR frame to it it'll take its color model RGB and than you're trying to convert to GRAY which is one dimensional . I hope it works this since I can't test it

Comment: @Engine:- so u mean i should not clone it and just convert the captureframe to grayscale image directly and then keep everything else the same.

Comment: yeap that what I mean

Comment: @Engine: not working man!! bdw whats your take on my approach? Do you think its conceptually correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the following two lines:

```
con = captureframe.clone();
cvtColor(captureframe,con,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

In the *first line*, you are making `con` as a clone of `captureFrame` which means that `con` **is a 3 channel image** and in the *Second line* you are trying to make `con` a **grayScale image which is 1 channel** therefore you are getting the fault related to the image type.

You should try to do the following (i am not sure whether your code would run after this or not but you should not get the current error after this):

```
con.create(captureframe.rows , captureframe.cols, CV_8UC1);
cvtColor(captureframe,con,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: :- my major error was the declaration of contours. I declared it as vector<point> contours but then i changed it to std::vector < std::vector < cv::Point > >contours; and it worked like magic. I still dont understand the difference between the two. Can you explain me whats the difference? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you so much for your help. I finally figured out my mistake and there was a problem in my declaration. I was looking online for some references and then i stumbled upon this code for object detection. The guy actually declared "contour" like this - "std::vector < std::vector < cv::Point > >contours; " and my declaration was "vector contours". My declaration worked for static images but it gave me this error while finding contours from webcam. Can anyone explain me the difference between the above two declarations? Also, as suggested by skm i converted my frame capture to a 1 channel depth image by using the con.create(frame.rows,frame.cols,cv_8uc1) and then converting it to grayscale image. This step is really crucial. So, here is my complete working code!! Thanks

```
     VideoCapture capturedevice;
        capturedevice.open(0);

        Mat frame,con;
        Mat grayframe;
         std::vector < std::vector < cv::Point > >contours; //this is very important decalartion


while(true)
        {
            capturedevice>>frame;


            con.create(frame.rows,frame.cols,CV_8UC1);
            cvtColor(frame,con,CV_BGR2GRAY);

            cv::findContours (con, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
            cv::drawContours (frame, contours, -1, cv::Scalar (0, 0, 255), 2);


            imshow("frame", frame);

waitKey(33);
        }
```